# how to redirect to root is flag is "false"?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I was trying to redirect to login page but it not redirecting to login page instead it login page content return to response in sinatra

```
get '/' do
    flag = false
        if flag == true 
        erb :index
        else
        erb :login
       end
end 

get '/list' do
    flag = false
    if flag
        puts "show list"
    else
        redirect "/"
    end
end
```

when i do call "/list" its redirect to "/" root then it should goto login.erb page but that is not happening instead of that it is returning the content of login.erb  into response of root call.

[image]

how to show the login.erb page on root call?

Comment: You screenshot shows you are looking at the output of Firebug in Firefox. Close that, the content looks to be behind it.

Comment: you are telling it to `render` the login.html.erb in `root`. This will not redirect to something like `localhost:4567/login` it will simple display the `rendered` page in the current path. Also you can change the conditional to `flag ? erb :index : erb :login`

Comment: @matt..You are very much intelligent ....Here its not rendering login.erb on page that what i uploaded this firebug screen shots.

Comment: @engineersmky, you are right and thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a redirect in the root as well. It sounds like when you go to / you want to be redirected to /login if you are not logged in. You can use:

`redirect to "/login"`

Instead of

`else
  erb :login
end`

You'll then need to add

`get '/login' do
  erb: login
end`

Comment: same thing happening in this scenario as i mentioned in my question